# Looping Regex in Python until Input is right

Tags: python, regex, loops

I'm really frustrated, no post on StackOverflow did help really...

Here my code:

```
    email_flag = False
    while not email_flag:

    print(Fore.CYAN + (" "*11) + " ■ " + Fore.WHITE +
    "Enter your Email Adress" + Fore.CYAN + " → " + Style.RESET_ALL, end='')

    email = input()


    if re.match(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", email):  
        print ("\033[A                                                                                                         \033[A")
        print ("\033[A                                                                                                         \033[A")
        email_flag = True


    else:  
        print(Fore.RED + (" "*11) + " ■ " + Fore.RED +
        "That's an invalid email!" + Style.RESET_ALL,)
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system("cls")


print(Fore.CYAN + (" "*11) + " ■ " + Fore.WHITE + "How many Accounts?" + Fore.CYAN + " → " + Style.RESET_ALL, end='')

Accounts = input()


if re.match(r"(^[0-9]+$)", Accounts):  
        print ("\033[A                                                                                                         \033[A")
        print ("\033[A                                                                                                         \033[A")
        email_flag = True

else:  
        print(Fore.RED + (" "*11) + " ■ " + Fore.RED +
        "Only Numbers!" + Style.RESET_ALL,)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The Email part is looped, but the "How many Accounts" part not. When I loop it, it goes back to the email part.

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: from colorama import Fore, Style
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import colorama
import sphinx
import ctypes
import re
import time
import os
import sys

Answer (score 0):

There's something strange with the indentation of the code, but assuming the `while not email_flag` line is supposed to be dedented, then that loop looks fine.

The indentation level of the code asking for accounts is not part of that loop, though. It looks like you need another `while` loop around that code to make it work as intended.

Comment: well if I add a another while under the other while loop its giving me this: Accounts = False
           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @VRX. Until you can provide a complete minimal reproducible example, along with a stack trace, I'm going to vote to close your question as of topic. Please edit the question instead of providing unformatted code in the comments.